# my custom taxonomy does not work and only returns the most recent posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called `cme-education` which I am trying to query to get only the posts that have a term of `covid-curriculum` however, the tax query does not work and only returns the most recent post. See my code below. my file is called **block_random-post-types.php**

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'cme-education', 
    // 'orderby'=>'rand', 
    'posts_per_page' => '2',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    // 'exclude=' => $currentID,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'covid-curriculum',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array('covid-19'),
        'operator' => 'IN'
    ),
  );

  $covid = new WP_Query($args);
  while ($covid->have_posts()) : $covid->the_post(); 
?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php echo "launch activiry"; ?>
<?php 
  endwhile;
  //wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below shared code:-
**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cme-education',
 'posts_per_page' => '2',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'covid-curriculum',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'covid-19',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**

Comment: hi, this does not work. it returns the same post even though I have added random parameter back in